# Line endings (also known as Newlines) in JS strings

Tags: javascript, regex, eol

It is well known, that Unix-like system uses `LF` characters for newlines, whereas Windows uses `CR+LF`.

However, when I test this code from local HTML file on my Windows PC, it seems that JS treat all newlines as separated with `LF`. Is it correct assumption?

```
var string = `
    foo




    bar
`;

// There should be only one blank line between foo and bar.

// \n - Works
// string = string.replace(/^(\s*\n){2,}/gm, '\n');

// \r\n - Doesn't work
string = string.replace(/^(\s*\r\n){2,}/gm, '\r\n');

alert(string);

// That is, it seems that JS treat all newlines as separated with 
// `LF` instead of `CR+LF`?
```

Comment: What's weird? linebreaks are not converted automatically when you open in another OS.

Comment: What editor are you using, a half decent editor won't care.

Comment: Do you retrieve your code via a Git client? There is a setting to convert ` \r\n` automatically. There are also some editors that do a similar thing.

Comment: @wp78de No, I don't use Git (I'm not fulltime developer, it's just a hobby). The question itself is more about research, self-education, rather then solving some real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found an explanation.

You are using an ES6 [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct your multi-line string.

According to the [ECMAScript specs](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-tv-and-trv) a

> .. template literal component is interpreted as a sequence of Unicode
> code points. The Template Value (TV) of a literal component is
> described in terms of code unit values (SV, 11.8.4) contributed by the
> various parts of the template literal component. As part of this
> process, some Unicode code points within the template component are
> interpreted as having a mathematical value (MV, 11.8.3). In
> determining a TV, escape sequences are replaced by the UTF-16 code
> unit(s) of the Unicode code point represented by the escape sequence.
> The Template Raw Value (TRV) is similar to a Template Value with the
> difference that in TRVs escape sequences are interpreted literally.

And below that, it is defined that:

> The TRV of LineTerminatorSequence::<LF> is the code unit 0x000A (LINE
> FEED).
> The TRV of LineTerminatorSequence::<CR> is the code unit 0x000A (LINE FEED).

My interpretation here is, you always just get a line feed - regardless of the OS-specific new-line definitions when you use a template literal.

Finally, in [JavaScript's regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) a

> \n matches a line feed (U+000A).

which describes the observed behavior.

However, if you define a string literal `'\r\n'` or read text from a file stream, etc that contains OS-specific new-lines you have to deal with it.

Here are some tests that demonstrate the behavior of template literals:

```js
`a
b`.split('')
  .map(function (char) {
    console.log(char.charCodeAt(0));
  });

(String.raw`a
b`).split('')
  .map(function (char) {
    console.log(char.charCodeAt(0));
  });
  
 'a\r\nb'.split('')
  .map(function (char) {
    console.log(char.charCodeAt(0));
  });
  
"a\
b".split('')
  .map(function (char) {
    console.log(char.charCodeAt(0));
  });
```

Interpreting the results:
char(97) = `a`, char(98) = `b`
char(10) = `\n`, char(13) = `\r`

Comment: It is incorrect that Google's JavaScript Style Guide recommends not to use template literals. They recommend against using line continuations (backslash escaped line endings,) and do recommend using template literals for multi-line strings over line continuations or string contatenation. The guide linked in the answer is the ES5 version when template literals did not yet exist.

Comment: @agermano yea, I cannot trace back what was in this recommendation three years ago and removed the link. The style guide shouldn't have been part of the answer anyway. Thanks. I am going to delete these comments after a while since they are now meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the regular expression: `/^\s*[\r\n]/gm`

Code example:

```js
let string = `
    foo




    bar
`;

string = string.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm, '\r\n');

console.log(string);
```

Comment: Useful, upvoted! But actually my question is about "what's going on here?" instead of "how to solve it?".