# newline matching regex - is /[\r\n]/ the same as /[\n]/?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, ecmascript-6

As far as matching a newline in a string - is `/[\r\n]/` the same as `/[\n]/` ?

I was reading this blog post:
https://davidwalsh.name/remove-multiple-new-lines

and it says to use `/[\r\n]/`, but I am simply wondering if that always matches the same as `/[\n]/`, or if they are sort of a  venn diagram where each might match something different.

Comment: very simple answer: if the letters are different, the regex is different. `\r` and `\n` are different characters (carriage return vs. newline), so just like `[ab]` and `[b]` are different patterns, the two patterns you show do different things.

Comment: ah yes, so `/\r\n/` is different than `/[\r\n]/`, in that way, if you can add answer that would help.

Comment: that is not your question. Your question is about `[\r\n]` vs `[\n]`, not about using [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) vs. not using character classes.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you had it right the first time, you understood my confusion - your first comment is right. When I first asked the question, I forgot about the `[]` braces.

Comment: give https://www.regular-expressions.info/ a read-through. It is _the_ place anyone with questions about regex should hit up first (once they know it exists, of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they're not the same thing. `\r` matches a carriage return (CR), while `\n` matches a line feed (LF). In certain environments, new lines are usually designated by `\r\n` (like Windows), while in others, new lines are designated by `\n` only (like Unix). They're separate characters.

Here's an example:

```js
const file = 'line\r\nline2';
const file2 = 'line\nline2';

console.log(file.replace(/[\n]/g, '\nNEW LINE:\n')); // one replacement
console.log(file2.replace(/[\n]/g, '\nNEW LINE:\n')); // one replacement

console.log(file.replace(/[\r\n]/g, '\nNEW LINE:\n')); // two replacements
console.log(file2.replace(/[\r\n]/g, '\nNEW LINE:\n')); // one replacement
```

As you can see, you cannot just use `[\n]` instead of `[\r\n]` - the output is different, they will match different parts of a string.

Often, when you want to match a generic new line in an unknown format, you can use

```
\r?\n
```

to match the carriage return if it exists, followed by the line feed.

As comment notes, it's true that *old* Macs used `\r` only, so to match those as well, you could lookahead for `\r` or `\n` and then match:

```
(?=\r|\n)\r?\n?
```

Comment: AFAIK Mac is using '\r' for Newline, it will not match your regex. To always get a match I use: ([\r\n]|\n|\r)

Comment: And of course a character class containing only a single character doesn't need the character class.  So `/[\n]/` is equivalent to `/\n/` but obviously `/[\r\n]/` is not equal to `/\r\n/` (the former matches only a single character whilst the latter matches two characters in a particular sequence).

Comment: @PoulBak `\r` applies mostly to the classic Mac and old versions of Mac OS X. Se also [this at superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/439440/did-mac-os-lion-switch-to-using-line-feeds-lf-n-for-line-breaks-instead-of). Some GUI apps may still use CR for linebreaks but anything Terminal related uses  `\n`.

Comment: Great, learned something new today (never worked with Mac, just read it somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, as often, it depends.

In general, `\n` and `\r` are **not the same**. Traditionally, in regex engines

- `\n` maps on most platforms (including Unix, DOS/Windows) to the ASCII `LF` character. On (classic) Mac OS systems (and old OS X versions), maps to the ASCII `CR` character.
- `\r` in turn, maps to the ASCII `CR` character, but on (old) Mac OS systems to `LF`.

As time goes on, the old Mac-style tends to become irrelevant. 
To prove this at least in part, here is a browser shot running Safari 9.1 on Mac OS 10.8 that matches [`\r`](https://regex101.com/r/W8MQMt/3) ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVPxm.png)) and [`\r?\n`](https://regex101.com/r/W8MQMt/4), ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4pKB.png)) against a single line break - only when `\n` is present in the regex there is a match.

However, there are still exceptions in JavaScript. For instance, if you define a multiline string using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) you always get a line feed - regardless of the OS-specific new-line definition. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49989049/8291949).

Nonetheless, if you define a string literal like `'\r\n'` in your source code, or read text from a file stream that contains OS-specific new-lines, etc. you have to deal with it.

To answer your initial quest,

```
\r?\n
```

usually is a safe bet to remove excess new lines.

Or, if really have to deal with the old Mac-style use `\r\n?|\n`