# Line terminator adds dot at the end of a line in npm test of Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I wanted to learn command line programming using Python.
I saw a to-do challenge on the internet and started to work on it by learning from the web. The challenge is to create a command line interface of a to-do app.

The challenge is titled **CoronaSafe Engineering Fellowship Test Problem**. Here is the challenge material on Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SyLcxnEBNRecIyFAuL5kZqSg8Dw4xnTG?usp=sharing
and there is a GitHub project at https://github.com/nseadlc-2020/package-todo-cli-task/

In the `README.md` I was instructed to create symbolic link for the batch file `todo.bat` with the name `todo`. Now, my first condition is that, when the symbolic link is called from the command prompt without any arguments, it must print some usage tips for the program. Finally, I have to use the `npm test` command to test the execution.

At the very beginning I got this trouble, whenever I use a `print` statement, I see a dot • at the end of every string which ends with a new line. For instance,

```
import sys
import random

args = sys.argv[1:]

if len(args) == 0:
    print('Usage :-', end='\n')
    print('$ ./todo help             # Show usage', end='')
```

The above statements when executed without arguments gives the output,

```
Usage :-.
$ ./todo help             # Show usage
```

Here, I noticed that for the first print statement ends with a newline, the string ends with what looks like a middle dot (•). Whereas, for the second `print` statement since I override the end parameter with an empty string, no newline character was output, and so the dot is not printed.  See the screen shot:

[image: Screenshot of command window with the error message and details]

What's wrong, and how can I pass the test?  My program does not print a middle dot at all.

Comment: working as expected. no `.` at the end of line

Comment: it is working fine on my device can you please share the OS information also ```end='\n'``` is default in print function so remove that.

Comment: Actually the execution was instructed to be npm test, and on testing that I got error and the reason for the error was the `.` . Let me add the snips to the question

Comment: @Rj_Innocent_Coder I knew that one but I was just testing with various end parameters and pasted that one here Also I am using Windows 10 currently updating to version 20H2

Comment: I'm also using windows 10 latest patch, works like a charm. :)

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65454092/unwanted-dot-at-the-end-of-print-statements-in-python-print-function

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be squarely inside the `todo.test.js` file.

In brief, Windows and Unix-like platforms have different line ending conventions (printing a line in Windows adds two control characters at the end, whilst on Unix-like systems only one is printed) and it looks like the test suite is only prepared to cope with results from Unix-like systems.

Try forcing your Python to only print Unix line feeds, or switch to a free Unix-like system for running the tests.

Alternatively, rename `todo.test.js` and replace it with a copy with DOS line feeds. In many Windows text editors, you should be able to simply open the file as a Unix text file, then "Save As..." and select Windows text file (maybe select "ANSI" if it offers that, though the term is horribly wrong and they should know better); see e.g. [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings) for many alternative solutions (many of which vividly illustrate some of the other issues with Windows; proceed with caution).

This seems to be a known issue, as noted in the `README.md` you shared: https://github.com/nseadlc-2020/package-todo-cli-task/issues/12 (though it imprecisely labels this as "newline UTF encoding issues"; the problem has nothing to do with UTF-8 or UTF-16).

See also the proposed duplicate [Line endings (also known as Newlines) in JS strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968130/line-endings-also-known-as-newlines-in-js-strings)

Comment: Using `npm test` for Python code is decidedly odd anyway. There are several popular Python test frameworks which would probably be better suited for this.

Comment: Thanks for your response...It was not a part of academics. It was a challenge like stuff in our country for student internship selection for UG students. Also, I thought of sharing the entire directory but there are over 7000 files in the npm_modules sub directory despite only less 50 mb in size. If you can take a look let me share the directory link in the question as well...

Comment: UG means Under Graduate, Bachelors degree. And, the drive link for the directory...
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SyLcxnEBNRecIyFAuL5kZqSg8Dw4xnTG?usp=sharing

Comment: The fact is that the deadline for the challenge had passed. But I wish to complete it for self satisfaction and also I can learn something. Anyways thanks for your response and kindness...

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

I replaced:

```
    print(variable_name)                                      # Or print("Your text here")
```

With:

```
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(variable_name.encode('utf-8'))    # To sys.stdout.buffer.write("Your text here".encode('utf-8'))
```

Now it worked fine in windows.

Answer (score 0):

First write your help string like this

```
help_string='Usage :-\n$ ./task add 2 hello world    # Add a new item with priority 2 and text "hello world" to the list\n$ ./task ls                   # Show incomplete priority list items sorted by priority in ascending order\n$ ./task del INDEX            # Delete the incomplete item with the given index\n$ ./task done INDEX           # Mark the incomplete item with the given index as complete\n$ ./task help                 # Show usage\n$ ./task report               # Statistics'
```

Then print it on the console using

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(help_string.encode('utf8'))
```

This problem occurs due to differences in encoding type of windows and npm tests. Also make sure to avoid any spaces after or before "\n".

Answer (score -1):

Why have multiple prints,when python prints can incorporate new line without having to declare separately, follow example below:

```
print("Usage :- \n$ ./todo help    #Show usage")
```

Output:

```
Usage :- 
$ ./todo help    #Show usage
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I tried nearly every kind of the python print statement but never worked and i believe from the earlier comments of the question, the problem is with either the JS or npm